# mysql +c# how to convert mysqldataReader to the right datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am trying to get a timestamp from a database (timestamp:01.40.07.016334) but when im trying to convert the mysqlDataReader to a DateTime, i get this "20-11-2017 14:02:19" and that does not follow the preset that i have made "HH.mm.ss.ffffff".

im my database (mysql) the timestamp is a varchar  and looks like this "01.40.07.016334".

```
DateTime fam = DateTime.ParseExact(rdrDagData[0].ToString(),
"HH.mm.ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            Console.WriteLine(fam);
```

Can somone help me?

Comment: Maybe don't save it as varchar but as (date)time

Comment: but i have to convert it to a string anyway so does that matter ?

Comment: You wouldn't have this issue for starters... Also you can't sort your db on date like this as its just "text". Other than that, inspect the value of `rdrDagData[0].ToString()` because if you specify the correct format the parse will work. So either the input string is wrong or the format is

Comment: The only time you should convert a date/time to a string is for displaying it.

Comment: Store your date values *as date values*.  Then formatting them for display is a simple `.ToString()` call.  Note also that you're not even *calling* `.ToString()` on your `DateTime` value.  You're just using the default string representation.  If you want to display it in a specific format, use a format string: `fam.ToString("HH.mm.ss.ffffff")`  Or, if the string value that's in the database already *is* the format you want to display, why are you parsing it to a `DateTime` in the first place?  Just... display the string.

Comment: i want i add the timestamp to a list so i can subtract them and then find how mutch time someone has spent at work that day

Comment: and if i use a the datetime domain name i will not beable to save the milliseconds witch i need.

Comment: @LessInformation Idk what you mean by `domain name i will not beable to save the milliseconds` but a `DateTime` object includes milliseconds...

Answer (score 0):

You have a `DateTime` variable:

```
DateTime fam
```

And you're using its *default* string representation for output:

```
Console.WriteLine(fam);
```

If you want a *custom* format, use a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
Console.WriteLine(fam.ToString("HH.mm.ss.ffffff"));
```

---

**However**, there are a couple of more underlying concerns here.  For one thing, if in your database what you have is a string value that's currently in the "format" you want to display, then just display what you have:

```
Console.WriteLine(rdrDagData[0].ToString());
```

**However**, the real question is... Why are you storing date/time values *as strings*?  Store your data as what it is, not as what you want to *display*.  You have date/time values, store them as such.  The only time you need to "format" them is when you display them for a user.

Comment: im trying to store the milliseconds and i don't think that is possible when using a time stamp. becurs i am using the timestamp as the primary key in my database and i do not want conflicts.

Comment: @LessInformation: I'm not 100% convinced that's the case, and you may want to look into the precision of date/time data types in MySQL for that.  But either way, if you're correct and you do *need* to store the value as a string, the original point remains that in order to output a `DateTime` with a custom format, use a format string in a call to `.ToString()`.

Comment: i will try to look it over and if you have the time can u see if there is somthing wrong with this bit
https://imgur.com/a/CEX62

and why is shift-enter a thing ?

Comment: @LessInformation: What do you mean by "see if there is something wrong"?  *Is there* something wrong?  Is something not working as expected?  This isn't a guessing game, if you're experiencing an error or unexpected behavior in your code then you need to *describe it* here.  Is this new problem related to the question asked above and answered here?  Is it a new problem entirely?

Comment: My bad im just a little frustradet that it is not working, but i think that i need to do some googling on the timestamp thing, and i thank you for all the help :))

Comment: @LessInformation: Well, if the problem being addressed in this question is still not working in some way, feel free to provide an update on the problem and I can continue to help.  If what you're experiencing is a new unrelated problem then it's best to open a new question rather than drastically change the nature of this question.